ndarray a obtained from b.diagonal() has its value changed after the b modification
I'm a bit confused by the behavior of the below code and wondering if someone could shed some light on this. Basically, I have a matrix called mat which is a numpy ndarray. I get its diagonal using mat.diagonal() and assign it to the variable diag. I changed all diagonal values of mat to 100. Now I find diag has its values all changed to 100 too, which seems to indicate that diag directly references elements in mat. Yet, when I check the memory address of the first element in diag and compare it to that of mat, they are different. What's the right way to look at this?
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mat_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
print(mat_df)

mat = mat_df.values
diag = mat.diagonal()
print(diag)
diag_loc = np.diag_indices_from(mat)
mat[diag_loc] = 100
print(diag)

print(diag[0])
print(id(diag[0]))
print(mat[0][0])
print(id(mat[0][0]))


mat:
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

diag:
[1 5 9]

diag's values change due to mat's change:
[100 100 100]

the first value of diag:
100

and its address
139863357577488

the first value of mat:
100

and its address
139863376059664


According to its docs, diagonal returns a the returned array is a read-only view

You can't know the address with id. First of all, id doesn't return an address (even tho, CPython implementation use memory address to build the id, that is just one implementation, and that is not the address per se). And secondly, that would only be the address of the python object (in your case the one wrapping the numpy.int64).
That python object is just build to wrap whatever numpy functions (that are opaque to python: python doesn't know when they are supposed to return the same values) return.
Simple experiment you can do to convince yourself how your id means nothing
id(diag[0])
# 139729998312368
id(diag[0])
# 139730045496016

See, not even two consecutive exactly identical call does not return the same id!
diag[0] is a call to numpy's diag.__getitem__(0). Wrapped into a python container that is different each time, as would be the result of a call to any function f(0), for which there is no reason to suppose that each identical call return the exact same result.
So, if you want to know where the actual int64 are stored, you cannot ask python (with its id function), since not only that is now what id is for, but more importantly, python doesn't know. Where the int64 are stored is an internal problem of numpy's library. So you need to ask numpy.
The best way to do that is using base imho.
diag.base
#array([[100,   2,   3],
#       [  4, 100,   6],
#       [  7,   8, 100]])
diag.base is mat.base
# True

But if you, insist on having an address of some sort, you can also
diag.ctypes.data
# 61579664
mat.ctypes.data
# 61579664

Or, for a more complete information on what data are viewed and how by the array
mat.__array_interface__
# {'data': (61579664, False), 'strides': (8, 24), 'descr': [('', '<i8')], 'typestr': '<i8', 'shape': (3, 3), 'version': 3}
diag.__array_interface__
# {'data': (61579664, True), 'strides': (32,), 'descr': [('', '<i8')], 'typestr': '<i8', 'shape': (3,), 'version': 3}

showing how the 2 are using the same 'data' but using different 'strides' and 'shape' to use it.

id(): "CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory."

Also, if you check diag.flags you'd see that OWNDATA is False because mat is the "owner" of the data.

@nocomment Yes indeed. The working part here (the one I was referring to) is "implementation detail". It means that, in practice, it is related to the address. But in theory, that is just an implementation choice, not part of the spec. It could change without warning in the next version. And most importantly, that is just for one of the implementations (CPython). The most common one, sure. Python is a language, not an interpreter, not a program (Cpython is, and is the most common program that interpret python language). And python language doesn't say anything about id being address

And besides, anyway, here, even if the asker said "I am 100% sure that my code will run only on current version of cpython interpreter", in which case, it would be an acceptable hack to take advantage of the knowledge of that implementation detail, it would still not work to use id, since that is the address of the object, but that object is just the dynamic ever-changing wrapper around int64 100, and says nothing about where 100 is really stored
